# how to apply global css styles to pages folder in next 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

This is kinda counterintuitive, the app folder has a global.css but these globals are not applied for the pages folder. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `pages/_app.js` and import your styles there:

```
import '../styles.css'
 
// This default export is required in a new `pages/_app.js` file.
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

More info - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/styling/css-modules#global-styles

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/styling/tailwind-css

Comment: the docs say that the path is @/styles/globals.css , but it can't be resolved